# What is a term for an invalid comment which is claimed to be the cause to something?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

A comment that isn't related and ultimately doesn't make sense. E.g., someone doesn't clear the garden and another person calls him by "dude, are you a woman/dog/cat...etc. (you could put any word here)?"

Another example to clarify this question, is when a person A doesn't do or complete a certain task, B. Another person, C, claims a D to be the cause of A not doing B. However, D couldn't, logically, be claimed to be the cause for A not doing B, since it doesn't make sense, logically (D and A are not related, so D couldn't be claimed to be the cause for A not doing B.)

The calling person saying something which he thinks is the typical cause of that other person not doing something (as clearing the garden), but actually it's unrelated.

Comment: This is the strangest question. You aren't talking about suspicion. Do you think someone suspects a person is a dog or cat? Read about non-sequiturs. They have nothing to do with *suspicion*.

Comment: Well, the person who calls the guy, who doesn't clear the garden, suspects there must be something wrong with him, as well as he wrongly, randomly suspects the other person is a cat/dog (any noun).

Comment: I added another description to clarify the question. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

More generally, a [non sequitur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_sequitur) perhaps?

> A statement that does not logically follow a statement that came before it.